# optimize laravel eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, optimization, eloquent, laravel-relations

i want to check the scheduling of a staff member for whole month. currently i m iterating through each date of a month, and then each hours in that specific day. and when i saw the debugger i got 1000+ queries. is there any optimized way to fetch all the scheduling from the staff table, stored in a variable and then check my condition through that array rather than hitting the server each time and getting data from db

```
#iterating each day for whole month
        foreach ($dates as $key => $today) {
            $daily = []; $daily[0] = 'fullyAvailable';
            $i = 1;

            #iterating each hours, 17 hours a day (17 iteration)
            for ($time = $opening_time; $time <= $closing_time; $time++) {
                $unit = $inst->instructor->hourlySubscribedUnit($today, date("H:00:00", mktime($time)), date("H:00:00", mktime($time + 1)));

                if (isset($unit)) {

                    $daily[0] = 'fullyScheduled';
                    $daily[$i] = $unit->unit_type;
                    $totalScheduledCount++;

                }elseif ($inst->instructor->timings($today)->count() > 0) {
                    $daily[0] = 'fullyAbsent';
                    break;

                } else {
                    $daily[$i] = 'available';
                    $totalAvailableCount++;
                }
                $i++;
            }
            $monthly[$key] = $daily;
        }


#and this is the relationship defined inside the staff model

   {
      return $this->hasMany(SubscriptionUnits::class, 'instructor_id')
      ->whereDate('date', $date)
      ->when($from && $to, function($query) use ($from, $to){
         return $query->whereTime('from', '>=', $from)->whereTime('to', '<=', $to);
      })->select('unit_type')->first();
   }`
```

Comment: What do you want to check? Write it out what you need: from staffmember, I want to look in the schedule table and see if he is active that day between hour (start) and hour (end). Let SQL solve your question. With dates, there is also a function "whereBetween()", that will help a bit

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is eager load the staff member. you can check how to do this in the  [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)